# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter

[image]

I'm trying to get details of user objects list.  I'm getting user id of user object by writing user[index].id,

but at the same time when i try to get cityname or name of the user like this user[index].cityname or user[index].id i got this error "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
"

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15fAP_B_CotC1MdAHa8UPGMKA_hlKn34z/view?usp=sharing   see this to check the error image

Answer (score -1):

Don't provide a null value into the text widget thats all. Handle the null case if your data is providing null values.